# Instaling factoextra R package- Instalando el paquete de R factoextra

Tags: r

He estado tratando de instalar el paquete factoextra (R) sin éxito. Este es el código que he estado usando hasta ahora:

```
library("devtools")

install_github("kassambara/factoextra")
```

Y este es el problema:

> library("devtools")
>
> install_github("kassambara/factoextra") Skipping install for github remote, the SHA1 (a335d1ce) has not changed since last install.   Use `force = TRUE` to force installation

¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: no es necesario que redacte la pregunta en ingles y en español, solo en español la descripcion del problema, puede incluir los mensajes de error en ingles o como los este obteniendo, (creo recomendable) Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En más de una ocasión me paso el mismo problema con algunos paquetes. La mejor forma de como solucione esto es:

- Volviendo a instalar R (de preferencia la versión más actual)
- instalando el paquete desde github (previa actualización de R)
- cambiar de repositorio (suele pasar que algunos repositorios andan caidos)

Bueno asumo que puede ser por algun bug del sistema, pero suele pasar.

Por otra parte, es importante que siempre estés viendo tu sessionInfo().

```
> sessionInfo()
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_PE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_PE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_PE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_PE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_PE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_PE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_PE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Hago este comentario porque, en más de una ocasión se me presentó problemas cuando usaba un par de paquetes, no recuerdo muy bien creo que eran el (MODIS y el Bfast o remotesensing creo).

Asumo en este caso que abría algún conflicto entre estos paquetes. ...

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Parece que ya lo has instalado antes, y que nada ha cambiado desde la ultima vez que lo hiciste.

Tratra de cargar el paquete usando:

```
library("factoextra")
```

Si eso no funciona, reinstala usando `force = TRUE` de la siguiente forma:

```
install_github("kassambara/factoextra", force = TRUE)
```